# Unable to obtain desired response from .aspx login page using Python and the Requests module

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests

I have been trying to log in to a .aspx site (https://web.iress.com.au/html/LogonForm.aspx - For source / initial cookie reference) which uses a javascript function `__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument)` to submit the form (very limited knowledge of javascript- so best guess).

My current understanding of HTTP requests is that, in the context of forms, they are mainly of a POST type request. I used Chrome to sniff out the request Headers and form data used when my credentials weren't typed in (For security sake) and they are as follows:

```
Remote Address:##BLANKEDOUT##
Request URL:https://web.iress.com.au/html/logon.aspx
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found

**Request Headers**
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:585
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=##SESSION ID STRING##
Host:web.iress.com.au
Origin:https://web.iress.com.au
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://web.iress.com.au/html/LogonForm.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/##ADDRESS## Safari/537.36

    **Form Data** 
    __EVENTTARGET:
    __EVENTARGUMENT:
    __VIEWSTATE: ##VIEWSTATE STRING##
    __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:##VIEWSTATEGENERATOR KEY##
    __PREVIOUSPAGE: ##PREVIOSUPAGE STRING##    
    __EVENTVALIDATION: ##STRING##
    fu:LogonForm.aspx
    su:Default.aspx
    un: # Would be my username if i had typed it in
    pw: # Would be password
    ImageButton1.x:45 # These two values change depending on where i click the submit button
    ImageButton1.y:13
```

and this is the code I'm using to attempt a login:

```
from requests import session

payload = {
    '__EVENTTARGET'             : '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT'           : '',
    '__VIEWSTATE'               : '##STRING FOUND FROM CHROME SNIFF##',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'      : '##STRING FOUND FROM CHROME SNIFF##',
    '__PREVIOUSPAGE'            : '##STRING FOUND FROM CHROME SNIFF##',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION'         : '##STRING FOUND FROM CHROME SNIFF##',
    'fu'                        : 'LogonForm.aspx',
    'su'                        : 'Default.aspx',
    'un'                        : 'myuser@company',
    'pw'                        : 'mypassword',
    'ImageButton1.x'            : '0', 
    'ImageButton1.y'            : '0' 
    }

requestheaders = {
    'Accept'                    :      'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding'           : 'gzip,deflate',
    'Accept-Language'           : 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control'             : 'no-cache',
    'Connection'                : 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type'              : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Host'                      : 'web.iress.com.au',
    'Origin'                    : 'https://web.iress.com.au',
    'Cookie'                    : '',
    'Pragma'                    : 'no-cache',
    'Referer'                   : 'https://web.iress.com.au/html/LogonForm.aspx',   
    'User-Agent'                : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Chrome/##ADRESSS AS ABOVE## Safari/537.36'

    }

with session() as sesh:

    LOGINURL = 'https://web.iress.com.au/html/LogonForm.aspx'
    sesh.get(LOGINURL) #Get request to get the session ID cookie
    sessionID = sesh.cookies['ASP.NET_SessionId'] #Grab session ID value
    sessionIDname = 'ASP.NET_SessionId='
    sessionIDheader = str(sessionIDname + sessionID) #Prepare session ID header
    requestheaders['Cookie'] = sessionIDheader # Add session ID header to requestheaders dictionary



    response = sesh.post('https://web.iress.com.au/html/LogonForm.aspx', data=payload,  headers=requestheaders)


    print(response.headers)
    print(response.content)
```

All I seem to get is the source of the page (https://web.iress.com.au/html/LogonForm.aspx) for the content and its headers as a response. I am not sure if it has anything to do with the `__VARIABLES` either but they don't seem to change, `previouspage` being the exception. Would I possibly have to extract these `__VARIABLES` to use them in my request headers?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed - could it have anything to do with my request URL being different to that sniffed via chrome? (Shoot me if this is the mistake)

Comment: I'd not manually set the Cookie header; saem for the Host, Content-Type, CacheControl, Origin, Pragma and Accept* headers. Leave those to `requests` where necessary.

Comment: Yes, you do need to post to `https://web.iress.com.au/html/logon.aspx`, not `LogonForm.aspx`. What do you want to be shot with, sir?

Comment: Oh boy, my first question and i embarrassed myself :( Thanks  Martijn, going to try with the new URL right meow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting to the wrong URL; your own data shows the form posts to `https://web.iress.com.au/html/logon.aspx` but you are posting to `/LogonForm.aspx` instead.

Note that the `session` object will take care of the cookie for you, do not set the `Cookie` header yourself. You should avoid setting the `Host`, `Origin` and `Content-Type` headers, and the `Cache-Control`, `Accept*` headers and `Pragma` are not going to have any influence how this works.

Comment: Martijn Pieters, Have my babies- and a marked answer.